# Android Converting Ninepatch Resource To Bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, nine-patch

I have a 9 patch drawable as XML. When I try to use `BitmapFactory.decode` to get bitmap out of it, it returns `null`. Is there anyway to get a bitmap from this resource?

nine_patch.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nine-patch xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/empty_icon_video" >

</nine-patch>
```

and the code is:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mResources, resId);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(yourWidth, yourHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.resId);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
drawable.draw(canvas);
```

Try this. Now the bitmap will be having the ninepatch drawn over it. You can supply a different width and height.

Comment: My problem is that I am inheriting from BitmapDrawable, so the super constructor takes bitmap not ninepatchdraawable

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [`NinePatchDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/NinePatchDrawable.html) API here -

```
NinePatchDrawable npDrawable = (NinePatchDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.empty_icon_video);
```